# Select com vários Left Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Realizei um `LEFT JOIN` considerando como atributos (`CPF`, `TEL1`, `TEL2` e `TEL3`). Por que todos estes? Por que o campo `CPF` muitas vezes retorna zerado em uma das bases, por isso estou considerando os campos de telefones também.

Conforme código abaixo, preciso saber se existe uma forma mais simples de realizar este cruzamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT
convert(date,A.DT_EMISSAO) as DT_EMISSAO
,A.EPS
,A.MAILING
,A.CPF_TITULAR
,A.DDD_TERMINAL
,A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL
,A.PRODUTO
,A.VERSAO
,A.CANAL_VENDAS
,COUNT(*) AS QTDE_REG
,LEFT(C.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8)) AS TELEFONE
,C.NOME_ARQUIVO
,C.DATA_BASE
,L.STATUS_FV

FROM [10.125.172.152].[televendas].[txt].[FichaDeVendasConsolidada] A with (nolock)

LEFT JOIN Carga_Outbound C ON (CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.DDD_TERMINAL) + CONVERT (VARCHAR, A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL) = LEFT(C.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8)))
OR
CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.DDD_TERMINAL) + CONVERT (VARCHAR, A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL) = C.TELEFONE

LEFT JOIN De_ParaVersao L ON A.VERSAO = L.VERSAO_FV

WHERE 
       (A.VERSAO not like '%MAPFRE%'
    AND A.VERSAO not like '%MAFRE%'
    AND A.VERSAO not like '%SVA%'
    AND A.VERSAO not like '%PRODUTO%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%ACEITOU%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%NAO ACEITOU%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%Ponto Adicional%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%SEGURO%')
    AND A.CANAL_VENDAS = 'OUTBOUND'
    AND A.MAILING = '3420'
    AND C.DATA_BASE IS NOT NULL

    AND CONVERT(DATE,A.DT_EMISSAO) between 
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(dd,-(day(DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))-1),DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))))
    AND
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH,0, getdate()))+1,0))))

GROUP BY
    A.DT_EMISSAO,A.EPS,A.MAILING,A.CPF_TITULAR,A.DDD_TERMINAL,A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL,A.PRODUTO,A.VERSAO,A.CANAL_VENDAS,C.TELEFONE,C.NOME_ARQUIVO,C.DATA_BASE,L.STATUS_FV

ORDER BY
    A.DT_EMISSAO,COUNT(*) DESC, C.DATA_BASE

---------------------------------------------------------
----:UNION CPF:-----
---------------------------------------------------------

 UNION ALL

  SELECT 
convert(date,B.DT_EMISSAO) as DT_EMISSAO
,B.EPS
,B.MAILING
,B.CPF_TITULAR
,B.DDD_TERMINAL
,B.TELEFONE_TERMINAL
,B.PRODUTO
,B.VERSAO
,B.CANAL_VENDAS
,COUNT(*) AS QTDE_REG
,LEFT(D.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(D.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(D.TELEFONE,8)) AS TELEFONE
,D.NOME_ARQUIVO
,D.DATA_BASE
,M.STATUS_FV


FROM (
SELECT
convert(date,A.DT_EMISSAO) as DT_EMISSAO
,A.EPS
,A.MAILING
,A.CPF_TITULAR
,A.DDD_TERMINAL
,A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL
,A.PRODUTO
,A.VERSAO
,A.CANAL_VENDAS
,COUNT(*) AS QTDE_REG
,LEFT(C.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8)) AS TELEFONE
,C.NOME_ARQUIVO
,C.DATA_BASE
,L.STATUS_FV


FROM [10.125.172.152].[televendas].[txt].[FichaDeVendasConsolidada] A with (nolock)

LEFT JOIN Carga_Outbound C ON (CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.DDD_TERMINAL) + CONVERT (VARCHAR, A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL) = LEFT(C.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8)))
OR
CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.DDD_TERMINAL) + CONVERT (VARCHAR, A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL) = C.TELEFONE
LEFT JOIN De_ParaVersao L ON A.VERSAO = L.VERSAO_FV

WHERE 

       (A.VERSAO not like '%MAPFRE%'
    AND A.VERSAO not like '%MAFRE%'
    AND A.VERSAO not like '%SVA%'
    AND A.VERSAO not like '%PRODUTO%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%ACEITOU%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%NAO ACEITOU%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%Ponto Adicional%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%SEGURO%')
    AND A.CANAL_VENDAS = 'OUTBOUND'
    AND A.MAILING = '3420'
    AND C.DATA_BASE IS NULL

    AND CONVERT(DATE,A.DT_EMISSAO) between 
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(dd,-(day(DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))-1),DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))))
    AND
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH,0, getdate()))+1,0))))

GROUP BY
    A.DT_EMISSAO,A.EPS,A.MAILING,A.CPF_TITULAR,A.DDD_TERMINAL,A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL,A.PRODUTO,A.VERSAO,A.CANAL_VENDAS,C.TELEFONE,C.NOME_ARQUIVO,C.DATA_BASE,L.STATUS_FV

) B

LEFT JOIN Carga_Outbound D ON B.CPF_TITULAR = D.NR_CPF

LEFT JOIN De_ParaVersao M ON B.VERSAO = M.VERSAO_FV

WHERE 

       (B.VERSAO not like '%MAPFRE%'
    AND B.VERSAO not like '%MAFRE%'
    AND B.VERSAO not like '%SVA%'
    AND B.VERSAO not like '%PRODUTO%'
    AND B.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%ACEITOU%'
    AND B.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%NAO ACEITOU%'
    AND B.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%Ponto Adicional%'
    AND B.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%SEGURO%')
    AND B.CANAL_VENDAS = 'OUTBOUND'
    AND B.MAILING = '3420'
    AND D.DATA_BASE IS NOT NULL

    AND CONVERT(DATE,B.DT_EMISSAO) between 
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(dd,-(day(DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))-1),DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))))
    AND
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH,0, getdate()))+1,0))))

GROUP BY
    B.DT_EMISSAO,B.EPS,B.MAILING,B.CPF_TITULAR,B.DDD_TERMINAL,B.TELEFONE_TERMINAL,B.PRODUTO,B.VERSAO,B.CANAL_VENDAS,D.TELEFONE,D.NOME_ARQUIVO,D.DATA_BASE,M.STATUS_FV

ORDER BY
    B.DT_EMISSAO,COUNT(*) DESC, D.DATA_BASE

---------------------------------------------------------
----:UNION TELEFONE 1:-----
---------------------------------------------------------

UNION ALL

SELECT 
 convert(date,E.DT_EMISSAO) as DT_EMISSAO
,E.EPS
,E.MAILING
,E.CPF_TITULAR
,E.DDD_1
,E.TELEFONE_CONTATO_1
,E.PRODUTO
,E.VERSAO
,E.CANAL_VENDAS
,COUNT(*) AS QTDE_REG
,LEFT(F.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(F.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(F.TELEFONE,8)) AS TELEFONE
,F.NOME_ARQUIVO
,F.DATA_BASE
,N.STATUS_FV


FROM (
  SELECT 
convert(date,B.DT_EMISSAO) as DT_EMISSAO
,B.EPS
,B.MAILING
,B.CPF_TITULAR
,B.DDD_TERMINAL
,B.TELEFONE_TERMINAL
,B.PRODUTO
,B.VERSAO
,B.CANAL_VENDAS
,COUNT(*) AS QTDE_REG
,LEFT(D.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(D.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(D.TELEFONE,8)) AS TELEFONE
,D.NOME_ARQUIVO
,D.DATA_BASE
,M.STATUS_FV


FROM (
SELECT
convert(date,A.DT_EMISSAO) as DT_EMISSAO
,A.EPS
,A.MAILING
,A.CPF_TITULAR
,A.DDD_TERMINAL
,A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL
,A.PRODUTO
,A.VERSAO
,A.CANAL_VENDAS
,COUNT(*) AS QTDE_REG
,LEFT(C.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8)) AS TELEFONE
,C.NOME_ARQUIVO
,C.DATA_BASE
,L.STATUS_FV


FROM [10.125.172.152].[televendas].[txt].[FichaDeVendasConsolidada] A with (nolock)

LEFT JOIN Carga_Outbound C ON (CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.DDD_TERMINAL) + CONVERT (VARCHAR, A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL) = LEFT(C.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(C.TELEFONE,8)))
OR
CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.DDD_TERMINAL) + CONVERT (VARCHAR, A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL) = C.TELEFONE
LEFT JOIN De_ParaVersao L ON A.VERSAO = L.VERSAO_FV

WHERE 

       (A.VERSAO not like '%MAPFRE%'
    AND A.VERSAO not like '%MAFRE%'
    AND A.VERSAO not like '%SVA%'
    AND A.VERSAO not like '%PRODUTO%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%ACEITOU%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%NAO ACEITOU%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%Ponto Adicional%'
    AND A.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%SEGURO%')
    AND A.CANAL_VENDAS = 'OUTBOUND'
    AND A.MAILING = '3420'
    AND C.DATA_BASE IS NULL

    AND CONVERT(DATE,A.DT_EMISSAO) between 
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(dd,-(day(DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))-1),DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))))
    AND
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH,0, getdate()))+1,0))))

GROUP BY
    A.DT_EMISSAO,A.EPS,A.MAILING,A.CPF_TITULAR,A.DDD_TERMINAL,A.TELEFONE_TERMINAL,A.PRODUTO,A.VERSAO,A.CANAL_VENDAS,C.TELEFONE,C.NOME_ARQUIVO,C.DATA_BASE,L.STATUS_FV

) B

LEFT JOIN Carga_Outbound D ON B.CPF_TITULAR = D.NR_CPF

LEFT JOIN De_ParaVersao M ON B.VERSAO = M.VERSAO_FV

WHERE 

       (B.VERSAO not like '%MAPFRE%'
    AND B.VERSAO not like '%MAFRE%'
    AND B.VERSAO not like '%SVA%'
    AND B.VERSAO not like '%PRODUTO%'
    AND B.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%ACEITOU%'
    AND B.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%NAO ACEITOU%'
    AND B.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%Ponto Adicional%'
    AND B.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%SEGURO%')
    AND B.CANAL_VENDAS = 'OUTBOUND'
    AND B.MAILING = '3420'
    AND D.DATA_BASE IS NULL

    AND CONVERT(DATE,B.DT_EMISSAO) between 
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(dd,-(day(DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))-1),DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))))
    AND
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH,0, getdate()))+1,0))))

GROUP BY
    B.DT_EMISSAO,B.EPS,B.MAILING,B.CPF_TITULAR,B.DDD_TERMINAL,B.TELEFONE_TERMINAL,B.PRODUTO,B.VERSAO,B.CANAL_VENDAS,D.TELEFONE,D.NOME_ARQUIVO,D.DATA_BASE,M.STATUS_FV

) E

LEFT JOIN Carga_Outbound F ON (CONVERT(VARCHAR,E.DDD_1) + CONVERT (VARCHAR,E.TELEFONE_CONTATO_1) = LEFT(F.TELEFONE,2) + REPLICATE('0',9 - LEN(RIGHT(F.TELEFONE,8))) + RTRIM (RIGHT(F.TELEFONE,8)))
OR
CONVERT(VARCHAR,E.DDD_1) + CONVERT (VARCHAR,E.TELEFONE_CONTATO_1) = F.TELEFONE

LEFT JOIN De_ParaVersao N ON E.VERSAO = N.VERSAO_FV

WHERE 

       (E.VERSAO not like '%MAPFRE%'
    AND E.VERSAO not like '%MAFRE%'
    AND E.VERSAO not like '%SVA%'
    AND E.VERSAO not like '%PRODUTO%'
    AND E.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%ACEITOU%'
    AND E.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%NAO ACEITOU%'
    AND E.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%Ponto Adicional%'
    AND E.VERSAO NOT LIKE '%SEGURO%')
    AND E.CANAL_VENDAS = 'OUTBOUND'
    AND E.MAILING = '3420'
    AND F.DATA_BASE IS NOT NULL

    AND CONVERT(DATE,E.DT_EMISSAO) between 
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(dd,-(day(DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))-1),DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))))
    AND
    (select CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH,0, getdate()))+1,0))))

GROUP BY
    E.DT_EMISSAO,E.EPS,E.MAILING,E.CPF_TITULAR,E.DDD_1,E.TELEFONE_CONTATO_1,E.PRODUTO,E.VERSAO,E.CANAL_VENDAS,F.TELEFONE,F.NOME_ARQUIVO,F.DATA_BASE,N.STATUS_FV

ORDER BY
    E.DT_EMISSAO,COUNT(*) DESC, F.DATA_BASE
```

Comment: Você precisa deixar sua pergunta mais objetiva. Tente explicar o que essa tabela carga faz? Qual os atributos entre as duas tabelas tem um relacionamento ?

Comment: Considerar telefone parece ser uma gambiarra. Deixando isso a parte, você quer que a combinação funcione com a junção do cpf ou, caso nulo no retorno, com qualquer combinação dos três telefones do retorno com qualquer dos três telefones da carga?

Comment: Isso mesmo, Jefferson...realmente, no mundo ideal, seria o CPF, mas não é a realidade, não tenho o CPF em todas as bases de retorno.

Comment: Rafael, os atributos da tabela, está na imagem acima.

Carga = mailing (Base de clientes para um call center realizar vendas).

Retorno = Base de vendas realizadas no mailing.

Atributos entre tabelas = (CPF, TEL 1, TEL 2 E TEL 3).

Por que estes 4? Dentro da tbl_Retorno vem muitas vezes com o CPF zerado. Por isso decidi realizar o cruzamento por telefones.

Comment: Não entendi :-(

Comment: @EdilaineMartins: Em cada uma das tabelas há colunas individuais para TEL1, TEL2 e TEL3? Se sim, qual o nome dessas colunas? No código somente aparece TELEFONE_TERMINAL (vendas) e TELEFONE (carga). // O cruzamento deve ser comparando o conjunto {TEL1, TEL2, TEL3} das duas tabelas OU deve ser individualmente, como em um produto cartesiano (TEL1 de vendas com TEL1 de carga, depois com TEL2 de carga depois com TEL3 de carga; TEL2 de vendas com TEL1 de carga, depois com TEL2 de carga depois com TEL3 de carga etc) ?

Comment: @EdilaineMartins: Seria útil se acrescentasse na descrição do tópico, para cada tabela, o nome das colunas diretamente envolvidas, como estão declaradas, o que contém etc. // Porque é necessário acrescentar '0' no número de telefone, quando ele tem 8 algarismos? // Cada tabela possui coluna que atue como chave primária? // Qual o número aproximado de linhas de cada tabela? // As colunas com telefone, na tabela de carga, estão sempre corretamente preenchidas, sem espaços extras?

Answer (score 1):

Edilaine, eis esboço de código que considera que, não havendo CPF em uma das bases, o cruzamento é realizado telefone a telefone. Para isso foi necessário transformar cada linha de cada tabela em 3 linhas, uma para cada telefone. É o processo de *normalização*, através do operador UNPIVOT.

Exemplificando o processo de normalização, uma linha que contenha os números de telefone

```
2732220987 27997820001 2740632020
```

é transformada em 3 linhas, cada qual com um único número de telefone:

```
2732220987     
27997820001 
2740632020
```

Você deve complementar o código, substituindo `colunas` pelo nome das colunas e `demais filtros` pelas condições de restrição a colocar em cada cáusula WHERE.
O código foi estruturado em CTE, de modo a simplificar o desenvolvimento e facilitar a compreensão e manutenção.

```
-- código #1 v5
-- gera o período de emissão
declare @dataInicial date, @dataFinal date;
set @dataInicial= CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(dd,-(day(DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate()))-1),DATEADD(MONTH,-2, getdate())));
set @dataFinal= CONVERT(DATE,dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH,0, getdate()))+1,0)));

--
with 
-- padroniza colunas de telefone de carga
transfCarga as (
SELECT NR_CPF, TELEFONE1, TELEFONE2, TELEFONE3, DATA_BASE, NOME_ARQUIVO,
       case len(TELEFONE1)
            when 11 then TELEFONE1
            when 10 then substring(TELEFONE1, 1, 2) + '0' + substring(TELEFONE1, 3, 8)
       end as DDDTelefone1,
       case len(TELEFONE2)
            when 11 then TELEFONE2
            when 10 then substring(TELEFONE2, 1, 2) + '0' + substring(TELEFONE2, 3, 8)
       end as DDDTelefone2,
       case len(TELEFONE3)
            when 11 then TELEFONE3
            when 10 then substring(TELEFONE3, 1, 2) + '0' + substring(TELEFONE3, 3, 8)
       end as DDDTelefone3
  from Carga_Outbound
  where 1=1 --demais filtros de Carga
),

-- padroniza colunas de telefone de venda
transfVenda as (
SELECT CPF_TITULAR, DDD_1, TELEFONE_1, DDD_2, TELEFONE_2, DDD_3, TELEFONE_3, DT_EMISSAO, 
       PRODUTO, VERSAO, CANAL_VENDAS, MAILING, EPS,
       case len(TELEFONE_1)
            when 9 then convert(char(2), DDD_1) + convert(char(9), TELEFONE_1)
            when 8 then convert(char(2), DDD_1) + '0' + convert(char(8), TELEFONE_1)
       end as DDDTelefone1,
       case len(TELEFONE_2)
            when 9 then convert(char(2), DDD_2) + convert(char(9), TELEFONE_2)
            when 8 then convert(char(2), DDD_2) + '0' + convert(char(8), TELEFONE_2)
       end as DDDTelefone2,
       case len(TELEFONE_3)
            when 9 then convert(char(2), DDD_3) + convert(char(9), TELEFONE_3)
            when 8 then convert(char(2), DDD_3) + '0' + convert(char(8), TELEFONE_3)
       end as DDDTelefone3
  from FichaDeVendasConsolidada
  where cast(DT_EMISSAO as date) between @dataInicial and @dataFinal
        and 1=1 --demais filtros de Vendas
),
-- normaliza colunas de telefone da cte transfCarga
transfCargaN as (
SELECT NR_CPF, TELEFONE1, TELEFONE2, TELEFONE3, DATA_BASE, NOME_ARQUIVO, DDDTelefone
  from transfCarga
       unpivot (DDDTelefone for Origem in (DDDTelefone1, DDDTelefone2, DDDTelefone3)) as U
),

-- normaliza colunas de telefone da cte transfVenda
transfVendaN as (
SELECT CPF_TITULAR, DDD_1, TELEFONE_1, DDD_2, TELEFONE_2, DDD_3, TELEFONE_3, DT_EMISSAO, 
       PRODUTO, VERSAO, CANAL_VENDAS, MAILING, EPS, DDDTelefone
  from transfVenda
       unpivot (DDDTelefone for Origem in (DDDTelefone1, DDDTelefone2, DDDTelefone3)) as U
),

-- seleciona casos em que há CPF nas duas tabelas
retornoCPF as (
SELECT V.CPF_TITULAR as CPF, 
       V.DDD_1, V.TELEFONE_1, V.DDD_2, V.TELEFONE_2, V.DDD_3, V.TELEFONE_3, 
       V.DT_EMISSAO, V.PRODUTO, V.VERSAO, V.CANAL_VENDAS, V.MAILING, V.EPS,
       C.TELEFONE1, C.TELEFONE2, C.TELEFONE3, C.DATA_BASE, C.NOME_ARQUIVO
  from FichaDeVendasConsolidada as V 
       inner join Carga_Outbound as C on V.CPF_TITULAR = C.NR_CPF
  where C.NR_CPF is not null
        and V.CPF_TITULAR is not null
),

-- seleciona casos em que não há CPF nas duas tabelas
retornoTEL as (
SELECT coalesce(VN.CPF_TITULAR, CN.NR_CPF) as CPF, 
       VN.DDD_1, VN.TELEFONE_1, VN.DDD_2, VN.TELEFONE_2, VN.DDD_3, VN.TELEFONE_3, 
       VN.DT_EMISSAO, VN.PRODUTO, VN.VERSAO, VN.CANAL_VENDAS, VN.MAILING, VN.EPS,
       CN.TELEFONE1, CN.TELEFONE2, CN.TELEFONE3, CN.DATA_BASE, CN.NOME_ARQUIVO
  from transfVendaN as VN
       inner join transfCargaN as CN on VN.DDDTelefone = CN.DDDTelefone 
  where (VN.CPF_TITULAR is null or CN.NR_CPF is null)
        and VN.DDDTelefone is not null
        and CN.DDDTelefone is not null
)
-- junta tudo, eliminando linhas repetidas
SELECT *, 'C' as Origem
  from retornoCPF
union
SELECT *, 'T'
  from retornoTEL;
```

Comment: Oi, @José Diz ... muito obrigada pela ajuda. Na verdade não completei o código, visto que ficou enorme e coloquei apenas o left realizado com o tel 1 (telefone terminal) e cpf como exemplo.
Sobre o CPF, acrescento um zero a esquerda do campo telefone, pois uma das bases para cruzamento vem com zero a esquerda e outra não, por isso realizo essa tratativa.
Agradeço pelas dicas sobre a descrição dos tópicos. abs.